# yii2- how to search a value using search model

Tags: model, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`. I have a model name `RouteMeters`. In this, I have a `meter_id` in which all the id's of the meter are saved. In my index view, I am showing the value of `meter_id` like below

```
[
            'attribute' => 'mter_id',
            'label' => 'Meters',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                if (is_object($data->mter))
                    return $data->mter->meter_msn;
                return ' - ';
            },

        ],
```

The view is below

[image]

But when I search the meters using meter number, the record is not found.

Below is my search model for `RouteMeters`

```
 public function search($params)
{
    $query = RouteMeters::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'route_id' => $this->route_id,
        'mter_id' => $this->mter_id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
    ]);
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role, [3,4])) {
        $query->joinWith('teamsuser', true);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'user.group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id]);
    }

    $query->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Now in my search model, I want to place a query which will give me a record of the selected meter number while searching in my index view.

The serial numbers of the meter are in my `meters` table with filed name `meter_msn` and I want to make a join with it.

I don't know what to do with my search model.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = RouteMeters::find()->joinWith('mter');

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'route_id' => $this->route_id,
        //'mter_id' => $this->mter_id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
    ]);
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role, [3,4])) {
        $query->joinWith('teamsuser', true);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'user.group_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id]);
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'meterTableName.meter_msn',  $this->mter_id]);
    $query->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUUQNbQ3TS8)

Comment: it's giving me error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'meters.meter_msn' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `route_meters` WHERE (`mter_id`='002998004581') AND (`meters`.`meter_msn` LIKE '%002998004581%')`

Comment: `mter_id` will contain `id` of a meter. I want to compare the `mter_id` with `id` and the filter the result by `meter_msn`. `id` is the meter id in table `meters`